# Trying to check whether function argument is an integer in python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function in python that runs if the parameter is an integer or returns an error message.  This is what I have.

```
def an_int(n_int):
    if type(n_int) is int:
        print("good")
    else:
        print("bad")
```

Can someone help?

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: It's better to use `if isinstance(n_int, int):`

Comment: Thank you for your help, everyone.  I am not sure why.  It wasn't working. Now it is.  I have used the isinstance(n_int, int) as @Barmar suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really understand what you are asking but I hope this clarifies your question:

```py
def is_int(n_int):
  if type(n_int) is int:
    print(str(n_int)+' is an integer')
  else:
    print(str(n_int)+' is not an integer')

value = 'gfjk'
is_int(value)
# Prints 'gfjk is not an integer'

value = 5
is_int(value)
# Prints '5 is an integer'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def an_int(n_int):
    if isinstance(n_int, type):
        print("good")
    else:
        print("bad")
```